# How to set snmp v3 context name in linux

Tags: snmp, net-snmp, snmp4j, snmpd

all 
  How can I set the snmpv3 context name for the snmp agent ?
  Can I set it when I create a new snmpv3 user or need to change the snmp configuration ?